# Jquery Ajax url path Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to design a message system for my website, but i can't get my ajax running.
So I make a simpler version of the interaction between the files.

Here is my file both test.php and load.php is under the root folder ( public_html).

i have the ajax function in test.php. load.php is just simply echoing "wow".

```
$("#test").click(function(){
 alert("Clicked.");

 $.ajax({
     url:"/load.php",
     type:"POST",
     beforeSend: function(){
         alert("testing");   
     },
     success:function(result){
        $("#result").html(result);
        alert("  sss  "+result);
     }
 }).error(function(){alert("wrong");});
 });
```

Now It works perfectly.

**...........how to set relative path  ...................**

Here is the more complicated design

3 files, all in different folder :

1. messages.php (under root)

   - showing all the messages
2. control.php  (root/panels)

   - a panel will be included in messages.php
3. load.php     (root/functions)

   - control.php will use ajax to call it then display result in control.php

so when user load in messages.php, it will load control.php then run the ajax call control.php.

I am so confused about how to set up these paths for ajax
( including control.php in messages.php works fine)

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error message in your developer console ?

Comment: Are you sure url that you pass to $.ajax correct? url: load.php, but path: root/functions/load.php i think, all right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the files you're trying to contact are in the root you can use `/[file].php` so that no matter which page you're on the path will be correct. It sounds like you have a relative path issue. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: ya it worked. but how do i set the relative path if 3 files are in different folder ?

Comment: That's when you'd have to use an absolute path, or create a dynamic relative path based on the current path. But absolute is the easier option.

Comment: like go all the way back to root(public_html) then use "../folder/folder/file.php" ?

Comment: Yeah, but `../` means 'the parent folder'. You'd want `/folder/folder/file.php` to get directly to a specific file.

Comment: k i see now. its not like require and include in php. Ajax url is using the absolute path. I got confused because i got many snippet php files including in my main pages and they also include some other files from different folder.  the path setting is a mess. :(  thank you!

Answer (score 53):

To understand ajax url, I have two things that should always be remembered.

1. If we put slash at the beginning of ajax url, ajax url pattern will be `hostname/yourFile`
example:

```
// current url: http://sample.com/users
// ajax code load from users page

$.ajax({
   url: '/yourFile.php',
   ...
});

// ajax url will be: http://sample.com/yourFile.php
```

2. If we don't use slash at the beginning, ajax url will add to the current url in the browser. example:

```
// current url: http://sample.com/users
// ajax code load from users page

$.ajax({
    url: 'yourFile.php',
    ...
});

//...ajax url will be http://simple.com/users/yourFile.php
```

I hope this things can help people who want to use ajax.
Happy coding, thanks.

Comment: ty let me try this :d

Comment: How do I check if a file exists in another folder (different from the folder where AJAX code is located)?