# Basic ajax/jquery POST failing

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, post

It's been a while since I've touched jQuery (a few years in fact) so please forgive the ignorance.

I can't get the following basic jQuery post to a PHP script to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<form id="formID">
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name">
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email">
    <input name="mobile" type="text" id="mobile">
    <div id="submitButton">Submit</div>
    <div id="result"></div>
</form>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
        $("#submitButton").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/fupload",
                /*data: $("#formID").serialize(),*/
                data: {name: "bob"},
                success: function(resp) {
                    //$('#result').html(resp);
                    console.log(resp);
                }
        });
    });
</script>
</body></html>
```

and the /fupload/index.php script:

```
<?php

$idInfo = "[ " . $_POST['name'] . ':' . $_POST['email'] . ':' . $_POST['mobile'] . " ]";
echo $idInfo;
return;
```

The PHP $_POST variables are not being defined (as per console output).  Using serialize() on the actual form data also results in the $_POST vars not being defined.  If I change to the GET method, then it works, but I need to post.

I'd appreciate any pointers on what stupid mistake I'm making.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the folder structure, i.e. where is the HTML file and where the PHP file. Try removing the `/` in `/fupload` as it will cause to look for the PHP file from your root, see here for explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627075/jquery-ajax-url-path-issue

Comment: the html file is deeply nested, and /fupload/index.php is in the root (hence the "/").

edit:

Thanks for the reference to:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627075/jquery-ajax-url-path-issue.  The ajax call is in fact finding the PHP script correctly - hence the console error:

Undefined index: email in /var/www/sites/sitex/fupload/index.php,

Undefined index: mobile in /var/www/sites/sitex/fupload/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `/` after `/fupload` like this:

```
url: "/fupload/",
```

This will run your code properly. If you do not use `/` at the end, this will send a malformed request to your php script. Since the post request values are also sent by using query string.

**Complete Code:**

```
<script>
    $("#submitButton").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/fupload/",
            /*data: $("#formID").serialize(),*/
            data: {name: "bob"},
            success: function(resp) {
                //$('#result').html(resp);
                console.log(resp);
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That worked - thanks.  Looks like best to always use the exact/absolute path to the script...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The settings of ajax should be `method` and not `type`

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST", 
  //^^^^^---- here you have defined as type   
    .......
})
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  Changing to "method" results in the same problem.

Comment: Rest of the code looks fine to me. Check your chrome developer tools and see if your request has the data that you are sending inside Network tab. Let me know

Comment: Looks like both method/type work.  The problem was the trailing "/" in the url (or use of absolute script path).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

get $_POST by this

```
$dataString = $_POST['datapost'];
parse_str($dataString, $dataArray); print_r($dataArray);
```

Comment: if sent data by serialize(); data: {datapost: $("#formID").serialize()},