# absolute path is not working in ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, relative-path

My file structure is something like this :

```
site

   module
         index.php

       js
         auto.js

     ajax
         auto.php

     index.php
```

I have included `js/auto.js` in `module/index.php`,where `auto.js` is an ajax call which passes data to `ajax/auto.php`.
**Edit** `site/index.php is also using js/auto.js` and ajax call is working fine for `site/index.php`

my ajax call in `auto.js` is like :

```
$.ajax({
       url : 'ajax/auto.php'
   })
```

After page load in its giving error in console `can not find site/module/ajax/auto.php`. 
I know its relative path error,what will be the correct relative path for this problem

Comment: use `../ajax/auto.php` for the correct absolute path to generate

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627075/jquery-ajax-url-path-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now its working Fine

```
$.ajax({
   url : '/site/ajax/auto.php'
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

call it like

```
url : '../ajax/auto.php'
```

and it should work fine

Comment: now its giving error for `site/index.php` and working fine for `site/module/index.php`

Comment: same path cant work for both files as they are located in different locations

Answer (score 0):

Use slash at the beginning like this

```
  $.ajax({
       url: '/ajax/auto.php',
       ...
    });
```