# How to get result from php to html use ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**Updated:** It still not work after I add "#".

I am new to ajax. I am practicing to send value to php script ,and get result back.

Right now, I met one issue which I can not show my result in my html page.
I tried serves answers online, but I still can not fix this issue.

My index.html take value from the form and send form information to getResult.php.

My getResult.php will do calculation and echo result.
How do I display result into index.html?

Hers is html code

index.html

```
<html>
 <body>
    <form name="simIntCal" id="simIntCal" method="post"
        >
        <p id="Amount" >Amount(USD)</p>
        <input id="amount_value" type="text" name="amount_value">

        <p id="annual_rate" >Annual Rate of Interest
            (%)</p>
        <input id="rate_value" type="text" name="rate_value">

        <p id="time_years" >Time (years)</p>
        <input id="time_value" type="text" name="time">
         <input id="calculate" type="submit" value="Calculate">
    </form>
    <p id="amount_inteCal" >The Amount (Acount
        + Interest) is</p>
    <input id="result" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

ajax script :

```
<script>
      $('#simIntCal').on('submit', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'getResult.php',
                data: $('#simIntCal').serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#result").text(result);// display result from getResult.php
                    alert('success');
                }
            });

        });
</script>
```

getResult.php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER ["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

//do  some calculation 
    $result=10;//set result to 10 for testing
    echo $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: Should be `$("#result")` in your success callback.

Comment: $("#result").val(result);

Comment: @ccKep@Ivan Barayev , It still not work after I add #.

Comment: What does the browser debug tools (F12) > network tab show as a request/response?

Comment: @ccKep It does not show any thing, but it give me Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in console.

Comment: That to me would suggest that you haven't included jQuery.

Comment: @RossWilson I included jQuery which like this <script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/DataScience.js"></script>

Comment: You're includes will not work without specifying the protocol, like `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` Note the 'https://'

Comment: @JayBlanchard My included have 'https://' . Here is new upadated :<script type="text/javascript"
 src="htt p://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="htt p://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Is `$` defined now? [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: also, you may have intended this, but you are trying to output your result to an input field, when perhaps it would work better to output it to a div?  If you are hoping to output to an input field, the current field is not inside your form tags.

Comment: @Thanks for your guys help

Comment: Have you check your path in ajax?
Take a look for this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627075/jquery-ajax-url-path-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.php

```
----php start---------     
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        echo 'Thank you, '.$_POST['name']; exit();
    }
----php end  ---------
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
function test(){
    var formDATA = {'name': $('#input_name').val()}
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php',
        data: formDATA,
        success: function(response){
            $('#result').html();
        }
    });
 }
</script>
<input id="input_name" type="text" value="">
<button onclick="test();">Test Ajax</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Try something simple, this is a very basic version of ajax and php all in one page. Since the button triggers the function you don't even need a form (doesn't mean you shouldn't use one). But i left it simple so you could follow everything.

Sorry when i added php open and closing tags it didn't show up as code.
Also don't forget to include your jquery resources.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the '#' in front of your css selector for result.

`$("result").text(result);// display result from cal.php`

Should be

`$("#result").text(result);// display result from cal.php`

Answer (score 0):

In your html file where you want the result to display, you probably want to be using a div.

Currently your code is using an input field:

```
<input id="result" type="text">
```

And what you probably want is something like this:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Unless you were intending to have the result show up in an input field inside your form, and in that case, the input field isn't actually inside your form code.