# AJAX / PHP working on localhost bu not working on server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make the button post data to another PHP file through AJAX. When I run the code on XAMPP it returns the data in a dialog box perfectly fine. However, when I run it on the server, it returns the current page's HTML structure.

**AJAX CODE:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post.php",
    data: {user_1: 'hello', user_2: 'hey'},
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

[SERVER ALERT RESPONSE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duKcI.png)

Comment: Can you try to change url as `url: "/post.php",`

Comment: Could you show us what's in post.php? Ajax is calling that file.

Comment: @AhmetEren Wow! This fixed it haha! I was so confused since it didn't return a 404 in the alert or console.

Comment: @ChristopherPantelli You can check this answer for explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26590904

Comment: @AhmetEren Thanks! It makes sense now :)